# path.join() adding tabs and newlines (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here, **filePath** is not showing the correct output, it is performing the path joining correctly but adding unnecessary tabs and newlines.

[image: Here's the image of output screen]

```
let folderPath = path.join(__dirname, topicName);
console.log(folderPath);
createDirectory(folderPath);
let filePath = path.join(folderPath, repoName + '.pdf');
console.log(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters must be in the data, they aren't added by `path.join()`. Thet only thing it adds are the directory separators. And you have a newline between `repoName` and `.pdf`, which is just string concatenation, not `path.join()`.

Use `trim()` to remove extraneous whitespace around strings.

```
let folderPath = path.join(__dirname, topicName);
console.log(folderPath);
createDirectory(folderPath);
let filePath = path.join(folderPath, repoName.trim() + '.pdf');
console.log(filePath);
```

Comment: You should probably figure out where that extra whitespace is coming from in the first place and fix it.